# Denying access to action with Zend ACL causes Navigation link to disappear

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation, zend-acl

I have a schedule controller with four actions:

```
class ScheduleController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction(){ ... }

    public function viewAction(){ ... }

    public function addAction(){ ... }

    public function deleteAction(){ ... }

}
```

So I've set up Zend_Navigation with an array like so:

```
array(

    ...other links here...

    array(
        'controller'=> 'schedule',
        'action' => 'index',
        'label' => 'Schedule',
        'resource' => 'schedule',
        'privilege' => 'index',
        'privilege' => 'view',      
        'privilege' => 'add',
        'privilege' => 'edit',
    )
);
```

And I've also created two groups in the ACL: users & admins.  I want to set it up so that users can access 'index' and 'view', while admins can access everything.  So I started with this:

```
class My_AccessControlList extends Zend_Acl {
    $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('user'));
    $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'), 'user');
    ...
    $this->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource('schedule'));
    $this->deny();
    ...
```

Now, it seems that unless I add this line:

```
    $this->allow('user', 'schedule');
```

the link will not show up in the navigation. Then if I add this:

```
    $this->deny('user', 'schedule', 'add');
```

users are blocked from the 'add' action, so far so good. But if I then add:

```
    $this->deny('user', 'schedule', 'edit');
    --or change it to this--
    $this->deny('user', 'schedule', array('add', 'edit'));
```

the users are blocked appropriately but the link disappears from the Navigation object.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array(
    'controller'=> 'schedule',
    'action' => 'index',
    'label' => 'Schedule',
    'resource' => 'schedule',
    'privilege' => 'index',
    'privilege' => 'view',      
    'privilege' => 'add',
    'privilege' => 'edit',
)
```

...you are overwritting the 'privilege' key three times, which results in an array with a key 'privilege' containing the last value 'edit'. The 'privilege' key should contain an array of four values